# Can't execute Rails rake task with cron

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I'm trying to run rake task with cron on Ubuntu with rvm

My `crontab -l`

```
* * * * * cd /media/sf_visa-tracker/ && /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake parse RAILS_ENV=production >> /var/log/visa-parse.log 2>&1
```

`which rake` says

```
/home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake
```

And I keep getting this error in my log (/var/log/visa-parse.log)

```
/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

Also, if I run `cd /media/sf_visa-tracker/ && /home/ruslan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake parse RAILS_ENV=production` from my terminal, rake task works.

Pls help ;)

Comment: have you tried working with https://github.com/javan/whenever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to use rvm with cron is to use [rvm's wrappers](https://rvm.io/integration/cron). Your shell sets up a whole bunch of rvm-related environment when it starts, and that's missing from your cron job. The wrappers are versions of the Ruby-related commands that take care of this for you.

In this case, if you have rvm installed to `/usr/local`, your cron job should look something like this:

```
* * * * * cd /media/sf_visa-tracker/ && /usr/local/rvm/wrappers/ruby-2.1.0/bin/rake parse RAILS_ENV=production >> /var/log/visa-parse.log 2>&1
```

You could also bundle up your rvm setup into a shell script that loads rvm before invoking rake; there's more details of both approaches in [rvm's documentation on working with cron](https://rvm.io/integration/cron).

Comment: in order to get rake executable path - use "which rake" to get rake path and then substitute "bin" with "wrappers" - check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to get something that worked and seemed clean. Here's what I ended up doing in case it helps.

**crontab**

`0 5 * * * /home/deploy/apps/myproject/shared/cron/daily_updates.sh`

I put the script in myproject/shared since I'm using Capistrano and that seemed like a good place for things that would persist between releases.

**shared/cron/daily_updates.sh**

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# You will need to update this as you bump ruby versions
source /home/deploy/.rvm/environments/ruby-2.3.1@myproject

# Since I had a separate place for Rails specific environment variables (e.g. secrets, app keys)
# you should set the permissions on that file to be owner read/write only
source /home/deploy/.rails_env

cd /home/deploy/apps/myproject/current
rake RAILS_ENV=production daily_update:send_updates 2>&1
```

Comment: I suggest u to use github.com/javan/whenever much cleaner and simpler solution :)