# How to solve "/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory"?

Tags: ruby, git, rvm, jekyll

I just deploy jekyll in a vps, and config git post-receive hook on it. When I push blog update to vps from my laptop, I run into this error:

```
remote: /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
```

I searched for a while, and tried the method proposed in this post: [bundle update: env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18936933/bundle-update-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory), i.e., executing the commands below:

```
rvm @global do gem regenerate_binstubs
gem regenerate_binstubs
```

But it doesn't help, the error remains. Since I'm not familiar with rvm or ruby, could anyone give me a hint?

Comment: Just ran into the same issue when pointing [Atom](https://atom.io/) to use a correct Rubocop executable. Top solution actually helped. You could probably accept the one you used, by the way :)

Answer (score 181, accepted):

use wrappers, example:

```
$ which jekyll
# /path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-version/bin/jekyll
```

in the returned path replace `bin` with `wrappers` so you get:

```
/path/to/rvm/gems/ruby-version/wrappers/jekyll
```

this is a script that will load proper environment and fix your problem, wrappers are generated automatically withing RVM.

Comment: I have to agree with Dex. Was going round in circles trying to get MailCatcher to play nicely with Vagrant/PHP/Drupal and this was the key. `sendmail_path = /usr/bin/env /home/vagrant/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551/wrappers/catchmail`. Wrappers instead of bin! thanks.

Comment: it works! i was trying to schedule a backup using the backup gem.

Comment: how do you exactly **replace** the path ? I guess I should not "delete" `bin`. I am using Mac. thanks

Comment: it works the same on mac or linux, the path with `wrappers` includes environment, the path with `bin` - does not - so it will not know about the rest of gems

Comment: WOW. Thank you! I cannot believe that this wasn't mentioned anywhere else. For those searching, I was attempting to setup PHPStorm to work with SCSS and needed the path `/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/wrappers/scss`

Comment: This really helped. But @mpapis, using RVM recently seems like bandaid after bandaid. (But maybe rvm1/ansible and Capistrano are more at fault than RVM)

Comment: the same issue was always there - loading binary without proper environment - the difference is that now you can find out about it early thanks to `ruby_executable_hooks`

Comment: Works perfect with `systemd`. Thank you.

Comment: when I run "which jekyll", I got a blank. What should I do?

Comment: For me, this helped me get a command running when I wasn't logged in as my usual user. Instead, I am getting a process started up via launchctl and monit on a mac, and this worked. Thanks!

Comment: This also resolved an issue with the Atom autocomplete-ruby package, which was giving me the same error when starting Atom.

Comment: I can't thank you enough for this. I spent a whole day trying to get my new deploy setup to work, and this did the trick. 
Thank you, thank you, thank you.

Comment: Superb. Helped me a lot in setting up resque worker & scheduler using systemd

Comment: This worked for me but only after another change. Having no jekyll I ran ´which bundle´ which returned similar path starting with ´.rvm/rubies/RUBY-VERSION´. There are no wrappers in that folder. Make sure to replace ´rubies´ with ´gems´!

Comment: Spent a lot of time before get to this answer, and it works perfectly

Answer (score 30):

You need to refresh the `executable-hooks` to the latest version by running following command in the `Terminal`:

`sudo gem install --user-install executable-hooks`

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem, but I have `bundler`, not `rubygems-bundler`, and my `gem` doesn't recognise `regenerate_binstubs`.

`rvm all-gemsets do gem update bundler` installed bundler 1.7.11 and fixed it for me.

Answer (score 3):

Updating ruby gems worked for me

```
gem install rubygems-update
update_rubygems
```

Answer (score 0):

faslane env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
re-install faslane

```
sudo gem install fastlane -NV
```