# Could not find 'sass' among total gems

Tags: ruby, netbeans, sass

I have previously been running an old version of Ruby, version 1.9.3, because that is what Ubuntu `apt-get` installs. Sass was installed with `gem install sass` and things works as planned. However, Sass would always tell me "Please upgrade ruby. < 2.0.0 will soon be not-supported," so I wanted to do that. I ran `sudo apt-get purge ruby rubygems libruby` and started to go to work.

First, I tried to install is with rvm, and that didn't go too well, so I did my best to remove that, but I may have missed some things, so don't rule that out. As per [this guide](http://ryanbigg.com/2014/10/ubuntu-ruby-ruby-install-chruby-and-you//) ruby *seems* to have been successfully installed. I then ran `gem install sass` so I can compile some css. The following are some relevant outputs to prove the correct installation:

```
$ chruby
   ruby-2.1.9
 * ruby-2.3.1
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]
$ sass -v
Sass 3.4.22 (Selective Steve)
```

However, when I try to integrate Sass compiling into NetBeans 8.1, the compiler throws this error for every file.

```
"~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin/sass" "--cache-location" "~/.cache/netbeans/8.1/sass-compiler" "--debug-info" <sass input> <sass output>

~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:319:in `to_specs': Could not find 'sass' (>= 0.a) among 11 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)

Checked in 'GEM_PATH=~/.gem/ruby/2.3.0:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0', execute `gem env` for more information
from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/dependency.rb:328:in `to_spec'
from ~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:65:in `gem'
from ~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin/sass:22:in `<main>'
```

Every file comes up with this error.

From reading around, it seems like it might be a path error. But it looks like I have the correct path setup.

```
$ echo $PATH
~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:~/bin:~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1/bin:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/bin:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
$ echo $GEM_PATH
~/.gem/ruby/2.3.1:~/.rubies/ruby-2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
```

I'm willing to try anything at this point.

EDIT: More information on why it might be a path error.
`whereis` for ruby, gem, and sass all output nothing. `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby` outputs nothing. `type ruby` outputs the path to the .rubies directory, along with `type gem` and `type sass` outputs to the .gem directory.

Comment: Can you post the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby`? Also, if the `rvm` command still works, you can use `rvm implode` to remove all traces.

Comment: @thesecretmaster `dpkg --get-selections | grep ruby` outputs nothing. I did the `rvm implode` but it left some traces in the `.bashrc` and `.profile` which I squashed.

Comment: I can write an answer for rvm, but thats not what your looking for right?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Not originally, but I am willing to try it.

Comment: What os do you have?

Comment: @thesecretmaster Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[RVM installation instructions](https://rvm.io/rvm/install)

1. `gpg --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3`
2. `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`
3. `source /home/rvm/.rvm/scripts/rvm`
4. `rvm install <the ruby version you want e.g. 2.3.1>`

Comment: With [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory) and yours I was able to get it to work. Thanks.