# how to auto start rails after maintenence?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, centos, centos6, ibm-cloud-infrastructure

i host my rails application on cloud server,
my server is using centos 6, 
and what i am trying to achieve is,
i want everytime server is restarted, i need my rails app to do an auto start.

i tried crontab, but somehow i can't get it working,
here is my crontab content :

```
@reboot cd ~/UAAdmin/urbanacecode && /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/bundle exec rails server -d >> deploy_log.log 2>&1 &
```

as you  can see, i dump my crontab result to log file,
somehow it's not working?

here is my dump result :

> /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory

this is very strange, because when i tried to run my crontab commands manually, i can see the server running.

i ran this manually

> cd ~/UAAdmin/urbanacecode

then

> /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.4/bin/bundle exec rails server -d

what should i do to get it working? please advice,
oh btw i am pretty new with linux OS, so kindly give an example
how to do it properly.

many thanks..

Comment: Here a forum about the exception, perhaps it can help you: [How to solve “/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory”?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory)

Comment: still no luck on this