# Google Firebase build error for iOS from Unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, firebase, cocoapods, firebase-analytics

I recently tried to setup Google Firebase Analytics for my Unity game. I am building it for iOS exclusively. I have not been able to get Firebase working unfortunately.

I am using Xcode 8.1, OSX 10.12.1, and Unity 5.5.0f3

Whenever I try to build to iOS from Unity, I get this error in console:

---

```
Error running cocoapods. Please ensure you have at least version 1.0.0.  You can install cocoapods with the Ruby gem package manager:

sudo gem install -n /usr/local/bin cocoapods

pod setup

'pod --version' returned status: 127

output: 
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError(Object)
Google.IOSResolver:Log(String, Boolean, LogLevel)
Google.IOSResolver:OnPostProcessInstallPods(BuildTarget, String)
UnityEditor.HostView:OnGUI()
```

---

I have tried just about every suggestion I could find online. I have installed Cocoapods version 1.1.1, and later I tried the beta version 1.2.0.beta.1, nothing has worked.

Typing "which pod" in my terminal yields: /usr/local/bin/pod
Typing "pod --version" in my terminal yields the correct version number (i.e.: 1.2.0.beta.1)

I cannot get this build to work in my game's project, or a completely empty project to which I just imported firebase and tried to build.
I also tried to get this working with the sample project at the following link with no success: https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity

I am out of ideas here... can anyone help?

Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Firebase engineer here.

The code reporting the error is here:
https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/b7a90e43d6c893622102ca53681f53a58dab1a24/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs#L760

unfortunately, it looks like we're not logging the stderr stream so it's tricky to see how this is failing.

It sounds like your pod tool is returning a non-zero error code, not sure why.  For example, on my machine I see the following:

```
$ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod
$ pod --version ; echo $?
1.1.1
0
```

As you can see "pod --version" is returning "0" (success).

Similarly, pulling the latest Cocoapods tool from github https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods yields:

```
cd CocoaPods
export RUBYLIB=$(cd lib ; pwd)
export COCOAPODS_NO_BUNDLER=1
$ ./bin/pod --version ; echo $?
1.2.0.beta.1
0
```

Where the same thing is happening, the pod tool is returning a success exit code.

Things to try:

- Contact support@firebase.google.com - we'll be able to work directly with you to diagnose and resolve this issue.
- Try [changing your LANG variable](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/21096/where-does-lang-variable-gets-set-in-mac-os-x), we've been tripped up by this code https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/8db5956/bin/pod#L3 in the past.  It's supposed to be handled by https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/b7a90e4/source/IOSResolver/src/IOSResolver.cs#L743 but you never know.
- If you feel brave, build https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/ yourself (you should be able to run ./gradlew in the root directory to build the DLLs) then you can add the stderr reporting, post / diagnose the error you're running into.

Cheers,
Stewart

Comment: This is what I get when I run those commands:

$ which pod
/usr/local/bin/pod
$ pod --version ; echo $?
1.2.0.beta.1
0

Any thoughts on what else could be wrong?

This is my LANG variable:
$ echo $LANG
en_CA.UTF-8

What should I be changing the LANG variable to?

I have already messaged firebase support at: https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/?authuser=1
However, I have yet to receive a response.

Comment: Ah sorry the formatting in that comment is awful... Long story short, pod --version returns a zero error code, and my LANG is en_CA.UTF-8 and I am unsure what to change it to.

Comment: Seeing the same results myself and have same issue here

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution? I gave up on Firebase because of this

Comment: We added more debugging in the 1.1.2 release of the SDK, any chance you have any more useful log output?

Comment: Using the latest Firebase SDK tonight. According to the Firebase website the SDK is 3.0? Below is the full output. Thanks! http://pastebin.com/7vuVHW0w EDIT: Could this be related to having two cocoapods installed? Typically for Xcode cocoapods is installed in a different location. Regardless, I installed it in the location the error wishes and still received the error.

Comment: Stuck to same error from last two days? Any solution guys?

Comment: @knert the error you're seeing looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247926/how-to-solve-usr-bin-env-ruby-executable-hooks-no-such-file-or-directory any chance you could give this a try?

Comment: @LebRob any chance you have a log you could share?

Answer (score 0):

If you have this error in your output:

```
Failed to extract git version from `git --version` ("xcrun: error: active developer path (\"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer\") does not exist\nUse `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app` to specify the Xcode that you wish to use for command line developer tools, or use `xcode-select --install` to install the standalone command line developer tools.\nSee `man xcode-select` for more details.\n") (RuntimeError),
```

...and IF you have a different path to XCode (like in my case, I had Xcode beta), then you should run the command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/
```